# How should I setup the schema for deletion subscription?

Tags: laravel, graphql, graphql-subscriptions, laravel-lighthouse

I tried

```
type Mutation {
    deleteUser(id: ID!): User @delete @broadcast(subscription: "userDeleted")
}

type Subscription {
    userDeleted(id: ID!): User
}
```

and I created a subcription where the methods `authorize` and `filter` return `true`.

But I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\User]

The `deleteUser` mutation works. Only the subscription does not work. I use **Pusher** for broadcast and the error appeared in the **horizon** dashboard.

Comment: The problem here is that the broadcast event is trying to fetch the user from the database, however that is impossible as you just deleted that user. Are you soft deleting the user?

Comment: I understand that. But how can I do it right? I just want to trigger the userDeleted subscription. I don't need whole user object. I just need to broadcast the id of the deleted user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a solution right now, just make a custom resolver where you firstly brodcast the event and then delete the user... (you can even make a custom directive that generalizes it).

Otherwise, you will have to dig a bit into the Lighthouse's internals to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late for you by now, but could help future developers looking for a solution.

I found that you can trigger the subscription in the model's 'deleting' event using Laravel's model events: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events This means that the model will exist in the database when the subscription gets it from the database, and shouldn't throw an error.

Ideally, the accepted solution would probably be the cleanest way to do it, but this works in the meantime.